# Reading email programmatically app not responding message

Tags: android

I was able to read emails programmatically but not without a problem. The "app not responding" message dialog box pops up. After clicking wait the app works fine. How do I resolve this problem because I just could not get past this. Every time I have to respond to this dialog when reading emails. Sending works fine. I appreciate your help.

Comment: You might need to post some code or logcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably downloading emails on the main UI thread. You should definitely use a separate thread or `AsyncTask` to accomplish the download, then update the main UI when the download is complete.

Read here on using `AsyncTask` to perform network operations off the main UI thread: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html

Comment: Thank you both Matt and Lawrence. Just the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are not using `AsyncTask` to read the email. Heavy work in the UI thread will cause the ANR message.

You should use `AsyncTask` to perform the reading. First show a `ProgressDialog` at `onPreExecute()` to let the user know that you are doing some work, read the email in `doInBackground()`, and perform any actions in `doInBackground()` after getting the result; you also want to hide your `ProgressDialog` here.

Take a look at the [official guide about threads](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html) too.